reading excel file gives me formula not the values
I am trying to read a excel file sheet and rows has a formula which refers to another sheet.
I am using maven library com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:3.5.0_0.20.3
My code looks something like this:
sparkDF = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")\

    .option("header", "true")\

    .option("maxRowsInMemory",100)\

    .option("inferSchema", "true")\

    .option("dataAddress", data_address) \

    .option("readFormula", "false")\

    .option("setErrorCellsToFallbackValues", "true") \

    .load(filepath)

I need to read just the values not the formula while reading a particular sheet

Does this answer your question? Openpyxl 1.8.5: Reading the result of a formula typed in a cell using openpyxl

I see openpyxl is tagged in this post, not sure if this is also an option for your workflow.
For that, you need to make sure that you have data_only set to "True"
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path, data_only=True)
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

...

I have bigger files and loading a using openpyxl is taking around 15 minutes just for 150 mb file and I have around 6 files of same kind to load. SO i want to eliminate the openpyxl and read using spark libraries
